# How to make C# Combobox Datasource and Databinding Different

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox which datasource is custom class list. I have a model class which has different type of property.

```
function List<CmbItems<string, bool>> getTrueFalses()
{
    return new List<CmbItems<string, bool>>
    {
        new CmbItems<string, bool> { DisplayName = "Y", Value = true },
        new CmbItems<string, bool> { DisplayName = "N", Value = false }
    };
}
```

I am using this in combobox(cmbMarried) datasource property. User `DisplayName` property as   DisplayMember and `Value` property as ValueMember.

I have other Model Class User. Which has property `isMarried`. Now i want to bind in combobox to that databinding.

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you using `Windows Forms` or `WPF`?

Comment: windows form app

Comment: did u try to get like this => `user.IsMarried = Convert.ToBoolean(cmbBox.SelectedValue)` ?

Comment: I want to use databinding because i used in textbox. Form is very huge, so databinding is helpful, else i know how to set in model

Comment: I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Comment: also answer updated

Comment: @er-sho I know this and i already do that. Only setting databinding remains.

Comment: What you actually want to do and what it means "only setting databinding remains"?

Answer (score 0):

There is casting issue in databinding. That's why databinding is not working and i put question here because i thought databinding and datasource not working simultanously.